# If animals were equipped with AI what would separate them from humans?

Tags: science-based, biology, artificial-intelligence

So the argument against sentient robots is that no matter how intelligent they are they they cannot be conscious because conciousness is linked to our biology.

But animals are conscious, expereince emotion,  and some animals like great apes are even self-aware.

So if we had the ability to give an animal like an ape or dolphin, the artifical intelligence and knowledge of a more advanced form of a modern-day Ai (think the movie Her, perhaps even less advanced, you pick) and add to that the ability to form human speech, what would seperate an animal from a human?

Comment: The process that you are describing is called "Uplifting" and is a major theme in [David Brin's novels.](http://www.davidbrin.com/books.html), most notably Sundiver, Startide-Rising and the Uplift war.

Comment: Philosophers question what separates them now.  What you describe is known in philosophy as the "demarcation problem."  Informally, it's the troubles that arise from trying to classify things as "X" and "not X" when there's really a continuum between "purely X" and "completely not X"

Comment: I think the proper way to ask this in "Worldbuilding" is to *tell us* how you want the animals to be different, and ask for help in figuring out how to make that sound reasonable.  So, where do you want to go with this?

Comment: Or Rocket from *Guardians of the Galaxy*... What separates them from humans now?  Only their lack of intellect?  Not their fur/feathers/scales, (some) lack of opposable thumbs, original brain capacity, capacity to affect the world around them (they'd have the ability to complain...), etc.  I frankly don't understand what you're asking for.  What's the goal of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a lot harder than you'd think and what you're proposing isn't an 'instant fix' for the uplifting of a species at all. It may not even result in a useful or even noticeable difference in any animal subjected to the process. Let's start with the concept of knowledge in order to explain why.

Knowledge is often confused with intelligence, and certainly in a human mind, intelligence is very hard to demonstrate to others without it, but adding knowledge to a mind in isolation does not make it smarter.

If we take the core element of knowledge (data) as an example, it becomes clear that a 3.2Tb drive full of 'knowledge' isn't 10 times smarter than a 320Gb drive full of knowledge. The drive doesn't 'know' what's stored on it and it can't function in a manner that can leverage that knowledge in any useful way.

True, data isn't knowledge as knowledge is the cross-referenced collation of data, introducing context and meaning to the data that is also supplied. But that in itself also introduces a limitation. You can't teach a dolphin English by uploading a dictionary into its brain; English (or any human language) is learned by children who do so by learning a single sound that has meaning for them; usually Mum or Dad, and then building on that frame of reference to build a vocabulary of sounds to meanings, which eventually becomes a construct that can store meaning through sounds (and later written words) which we call language (and perhaps even more importantly semantics). So, unless your animal has words introduced to it in a manner that they can understand from the first few through to the building of their vocabulary, words are just meaningless abstractions that cannot provide context or benefit to thinking ability.

But wait (I hear you say), I also mentioned AI. That has to help, surely?

Now we get to the nub of the problem. What really is intelligence? Intelligence is the ability to identify (and recognise) patterns. That's all it is. Humans have a high level of natural intelligence and therefore can recognise more complex patterns and identify the simple ones faster than other animals. This is why babies can learn language; they start by forming simple patterns in their environment and hear their father constantly say 'Dada' at them, while their mother says 'Muma', both hoping to have their word repeated first. Babies learn to repeat what they hear, what they see done around them, and then stimulus / response patterns are manifested.

Father is happy when he hears 'Dada'. Mother is happy when she hears 'Muma', and those words carry meaning. Pleasure, cuddles, etc. from a specific person. That word is associated with them, and it forms the basis of a language structure because the mind has been 'trained' to recognise patterns in sound that trigger behaviours in others. We build on that foundation through our childhood and in to adulthood because our ability to perceive patterns has been heavily trained around this concept of sounds (and eventually words) as abstract representations of our environment.

Then we use that to build math skills, social integration skills, etc.

The point of all this is that we all build up a 'hidden layer' of meaning in our minds against which our psychology and intelligence is based. That starts being trained from the beginning and continues to expand and be trained with new concepts and understanding as they are presented.

AIs are designed to mimic that. They are presented with training data, against which they build up their own 'hidden layer' of nodes that forms a pattern against the problem domain. All 'yes' cases tend to look like X, all 'no' cases tend to look like Y. Then, when you used the trained AI to detect whether the answer is yes or no, it's literally just matching the case pattern against X and Y to see which is the better fit. If the answer comes back 51% yes (or higher, 49% no (or lower), then the answer is yes.

The point of this being, that an AI implanted in an animal would have to be implanted *at birth* and the animal would have to be *capable of integrating its pattern identification and recognition capabilities into its own neural capacity*. This is no simple matter, and would involve a biological interface beyond what we currently possess. Even if we *did* possess it, we're far more likely to use it on ourselves in any event. Such a capability would greatly extend our own cognitive limits as even modern AIs can identify and recognise patterns beyond our human cognitive limits (although they can't *understand* them, but that's a topic outside the scope of this question).

Bottom line is that even **if** you could uplift an animal in this manner, you can't just make it instantly human level smart and knowledgeable. All you could do is give the animal the capacity to learn that a human does and then educate it the best way you know how to do.

Which, when you get right down to it, is **exactly** what we do with human children today. So in that sense, there wouldn't be a difference, especially if the caregivers of the uplifted animals are willing to invest the same level of emotional support and attention in the animals that parents do for their kids.

Answer (score 3):

There would be divisions but most of them would not be in humanity's favor.  Animals living in the wild have been exposed to evolutionary motivation which we higher primates have spared ourselves from through strategic cognition and tool use.

- Cats with human intelligence would be more ruthless than our most power-mad politicians.
- Birds would have flight, which still trumps intelligence in my book for raw joy generating potential.
- Dolphins and whales have their own brand of flight and the ability to go places that primates cannot easily follow.

and Dogs with human intelligence would be the big winner in your skewed genetic lottery.  Happy, friendly, and loyal with a strong pack mentality and the ability to be vicious when needed, dogs are a superior life form.  Add intelligence to that list and they would soon rule the world.

As for us Apes, all we have on our side is fingers; and in the age of "Alexa", "Siri" and "Cortana", the ability to type is quickly loosing its value.

Comment: This answer. The differences would be rooted *in their physiology*. The other thing is, how functional are these uplifted creatures (e.g. do they need keyboards? Do they need to speak, and if so, do they have cybernetic vocalizers? Probably most important: *why were they created?* And has this world made the accessibility accomodations for them, or are they still expected to climb stairs and hit buttons and use human bathrooms?